# Shiny: if statement with input variable in server.R might be NULL

Tags: r, null, shiny

EDIT: Ok, I did a bit more problem solving and the issue is not in the `if(boolean)` statement, it's actually in my `filter()` statement within the `if()` statement:

`bar_mcgun <- bar_mcgun %>% filter(region == input$area)`

`input$area` is returning `NULL`. `area` is an `inputid` variable with in the following `renderUI()` statement:

```
output$region <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "area", label =  "Choose a region:", choices =  c("Midwest", "Northeast",
        "South Central", "South Atlantic", "West"), selected =  "Northeast")
})
```

It seems that `input$area` is hidden for some reason. Please help.

I also get the following error when I try to call `input$location`:

`Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)`

---

I've been getting kicked out of RStudio for the past three hours trying to run an app. I'm pretty confident that the error has something to do with the connection between the `radioButtons()` in my ui.R file and the `if-statements` in my server.R file.

I checked my log file and I see 'Null is not an object'. I isolated the code to check to see if there was an error with `read.csv2` and the subsequent data manipulations, but everything shows up.

Please let me know if you have any idea where the 'Null' is coming from.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("McGun"),

 sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Look at number of Gundealers, McDonald's, hospitals, and/or Population of states by region:"),

      radioButtons('view', 'View U.S.A data according to state or region:', c('states', 'regions'), 'regions'),

      conditionalPanel(
        "input.view == 'states'",
        uiOutput('state')
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        "input.view == 'regions'",
        uiOutput('region')
      ),

      checkboxGroupInput("data", 
                  label = "Data of interest:",
                  c( 'population','gundealers', "mcdonalds", 'hospitals'),
                  c( 'population','gundealers', "mcdonalds", 'hospitals')),

      selectInput('pop', 'Population by:', c('1000', '10000', '100000'), '10000')

      ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('barplot')
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
mcgun <- read.csv2("data/mcgun.csv2")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
location <- state.abb
location[51] <- 'DC'
location <- sort(location)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$state <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = 'location',label = 'Choose a state:', choices = location, selected = location[1])
  })


  output$region <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "area", label =  "Choose a region:", choices =         c("Midwest", "Northeast",
                 "South Central", "South Atlantic", "West"), selected =  "Northeast")
  })

  output$barplot <- renderPlot({

    scale_mcgun <- mcgun %>% mutate(population = round(population/as.integer(input$pop)))
    scale_mcgun <- melt(scale_mcgun, id.vars = c('state', 'region'))
    scale_mcgun <- scale_mcgun %>% arrange(state, variable)

    if(is.null(input$data)==T){return()}

    bar_mcgun <- data.frame()
    for(i in 1:length(input$data)){bar_mcgun <- rbind(bar_mcgun, filter(scale_mcgun, variable == input$data[i]))}

    if(input$view == 'regions'){

      bar_mcgun <- bar_mcgun %>% filter(region == input$area)

      ggplot(bar_mcgun, aes(state, value, fill = as.factor(variable))) +
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
    }

    if(input$view == 'states'){ 

      bar_mcgun <- bar_mcgun %>% filter(state == input$location)

      ggplot(bar_mcgun, aes(state, value, fill = as.factor(variable))) +
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')

    }
  })

})
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could it be that using return() retuns a NULL to plotOutput('barplot'). 
Is there more context in your log file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `return()` just returns an empty `mainPanel()`. I put it there just in case none of the checkboxes were clicked.

Comment: I also don't understand how to read log files, It was very big and I've never looked at a log file before. The only information that stood out was the Java: Null is not an object error

Answer (score 2):

Ok, my problem was two-fold: I didn't use reactive statements and I used reactive statements with dplyr.

For example:

```
output$region <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "area", label =  "Choose a region:", choices =  c("Midwest", "Northeast",
        "South Central", "South Atlantic", "West"), selected =  "Northeast")
})
```

Because the `selectInput()` function is within the `renderUI()` function, the former is now a reactive function. This new reactivity means that I can no longer call `input$area` like I would normally. i now have to make a separate reactive variable, and then call the variable as a function:

```
area <- reactive({ input$area })
area() #will equal input$area
```

The second issue was using reactive variables in the `dplyr filter()` function. Apparently, there is a conflict between the two since `shiny` and `dplyr` use non-standard formats. I think there is a way to resolve this conflict, but I straight up just couldn't understand it and took the lazy root by just getting rid of `dplyr` and using the `base` filtering method.

Cheers.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("McGun"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Look at number of Gundealers, McDonald's, Hospitals, and/or Population of states either individually or by region:"),

      radioButtons('view', 'View U.S.A data according to state or region:', c('states', 'regions'), 'regions'),

      conditionalPanel(
        "input.view == 'states'",
        uiOutput('state')
      ),

      conditionalPanel(
        "input.view == 'regions'",
        uiOutput('region')
      ),

       checkboxGroupInput("data", 
                  label = "Data of interest:",
                  c( 'population','gundealers', "mcdonalds", 'hospitals'),
                  c( 'population','gundealers', "mcdonalds", 'hospitals')),

      selectInput('pop', 'Population by:', c('1000', '10000', '100000'), '10000')

      ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('barplot')
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
mcgun <- read.csv2("data/mcgun.csv2")
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
location <- sort(c(state.abb, 'DC'))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$state <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = 'location',label = 'Choose a state:', choices = location, selected = location[1])
  })

  output$region <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "area", label =  "Choose a region:", choices =  c("Midwest", "Northeast",
                 "South Central", "South Atlantic", "West"), selected =  "Northeast")
  })

  output$barplot <- renderPlot({
    scale_mcgun <- mcgun %>% mutate(population = round(population/as.integer(input$pop)))
    scale_mcgun <- melt(scale_mcgun, id.vars = c('state', 'region'))
    scale_mcgun <- scale_mcgun %>% arrange(state, variable)

    if(is.null(input$data)==T){return()}
    bar_mcgun <- data.frame()
    for(i in 1:length(input$data)){bar_mcgun <- rbind(bar_mcgun, filter(scale_mcgun, variable == input$data[i]))}

    stateorregion <- reactive({ input$view })

    if( stateorregion() == 'regions' ){
      area <- reactive({ input$area })
      ismatch <- bar_mcgun[,2] == area()
      bar_mcgun <-  bar_mcgun[ismatch,]

    }

    if( stateorregion() == 'states' ){ 
      location <- reactive({ input$location })
      ismatch <- bar_mcgun[,1] == location()
      bar_mcgun <- bar_mcgun[ismatch,]

    }

    ggplot(bar_mcgun, aes(state, value, fill = as.factor(variable))) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')

  })

})
```